# Error message of TPM after run "dmesg | grep -i error"

Tags: dmesg, tpm

I found the error message of TPM after "dmesg | grep -i error".

1. ima: Error Communicating to TPM Chip
2. tpm tpm0:tpm_try_transmit: send() error -5

Could someone explain the error message and how could I fix it?

Thanks.